# Hide/show components in a ZUL file with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, zk

I am developing a web application with ZK. I have implemented Spring Security facilities so that, based on the nature of the user logged in, a page should display or not certain components. I have been looking everywhere and there seem not to be an example for such thing. Does anyone know if it's feasible in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You can find a [sample](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Spring%20Essentials/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring%20Security/Add%20Security%20in%20the%20View%20Layer) in zk docs, but I will explain a bit.

Many ZK tags, maybe all I am not sure, can have the `if` [attribute](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/Conditional_Evaluation).
This makes it possible, to show Components under defined conditions.

Now, you can combine this with the zk security tag lib.

```
<?taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/zkspring/security" prefix="sec"?>
```

So you can use the defined prefix for a Spring-Role check.

```
if="${sec:isAllGranted('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')}"
```

Of course, you can use this for visible attribute too.
But I think due to the security aspect this isn't a good idea in general.

Keep in mind, that you can use [Spring annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-global-method) as well.

```
@PreAuthorize("checkWhatYouLike")
public void myEventHandler(Event ev){
   ...
}
```

And take a look at the [`SecurityUtil`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zkspring-security/org/zkoss/spring/security/SecurityUtil.html) class of zks Spring package.

Comment: Does it help or still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **visible** attribute to hide and show the component according to user logged in .
I am not that much time to create a demo example right now but what i can suggest you WHat you can do here you can put all components id in DB with username something like we can say if we have 5 components in page let us suppose

Comment: Can you please show me a little example or give me a deeper explanation?

Comment: Then you have to given the some more details are you going to save components id in DB so it will come according to user login? You are using MVC or MVVM? Also you can check Nabil answer he explained in brief